# Free-Jqgrid width is 1px no matter what I specify

Tags: free-jqgrid

I am using version 4.13.6.
When I specify the widths, and it is rendered in the view, the table is only 336 px wide.  I can use developer tools to uncheck the element.style { width: 1px } and it will fill the page.  How can I get it to be 100% width?

Jquery:

```
    @model RSVPTestWindowsAuth.Models.JsonClass

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/free-jqGrid/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/free-jqGrid/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var data = @Html.Raw(@Model.jsonCls);

    $(document).ready(
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        $("#jqgrid1").jqGrid({

            url: '@Url.Action("List", "Home")',
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            shrinkToFit: false,
            mtype: 'GET',
            width: '100%',
            colNames: ["Tracis", "CrimeType", "Supp", "Arrest", "Type", "Reported"],
            colModel: [
                { name: "Tracis" , label: "Tracis", width:20},
                { name: "CrimeType", width:400},
                { name: "Supp", formatter: 'checkbox' ,width:5 },
                { name: "Arrest" , formatter: 'checkbox', width:5},
                { name: "Type", formatter: 'string', width:25},
                { name: "Reported", formatter: 'date', sorttype: 'date', datefmt:'m/d/yyyy HH:MM:SS', width:20}

            ],
            cmTemplate: { editable: true },
            rowNum: 20,        // Total records to show at a time by default
            loadonce: true,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],  // For Paging
            pager: '#gridpager',
            datastr: data,
            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows",
                page: "currpage",
                total: "totalpages",
                records: "totalrecords",
                repeatitems: false
            },
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            autowidth: true,
            height: 'auto',
            hoverrows: true,
            caption: "Reports Available"
        });
    }));

</script>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
}
<!-- import the included stylesheet for some (very basic) default styling -->
<link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<h2>Reports Available:</h2><br />

<table>
    <tr>
       <table id="jqgrid1"></table>
       <div id="gridpager"></div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is what the screen looks like when it renders:
[image]

Here is what it looks like when I use the developer tools to remove the 1px:

[image]

Comment: It's not quite clear which results you want to have. You use, for example, `shrinkToFit: false` option, which prevents shrinking/expanding the **column width**. One should you use `shrinkToFit: false` option in combination with `autowidth: true` only if you want to increase the **width of the grid without increasing the width of the columns**. It creates additional free space on the right size of the last column. It's helpful if you insert the picture, which demonstrate how the grid looks now.

Comment: Moreover, you use some other strange combination of the options `datatype: "jsonstring", datastr: data` from one side and `url: '@Url.Action("List", "Home")', mtype: 'GET', loadonce: true`. Wrom which source you need to load the data? The value `jsonReader`, seems be strange too. Could you include an example of input data for the grid (two rows would be enough)? Which field of input data is the unique id of the item, which can be used as the rowid (id attribute of `<tr>` elements)?

Comment: Here is what they data looks like:      {page:1,total:1,records:1, rows: [{"id":"136746","Tracis":"2015059059","CrimeType":"Quarreling","Supp":false,"Arrest":false,"Type":"Incident","Reported":"1/8/2016 10:43:31 PM"},{"id":"128252","Tracis":"2015070385","CrimeType":"Lost Property","Supp":false,"Arrest":false,"Type":"Incident","Reported":"11/20/2015 12:36:36 AM"}]}

Comment: I am loading this in MVC by passing this as a model to the jquery.  So the model is defined only as a string.  That is why I am using a jsonstring.  If I dont use a @Html.Raw then I get an unexpected token &. ( I guess because it sees the quotes as &Quote.

Comment: I modified my original post to include a couple of screen shots.

Comment: Now I see from the pictures, what you mean. The setting `width:1px` for the main grid (bdiv) or **any** other value is required for `table-layout: fixed;` tables, which uses jqGrid. See [the lines](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.6/css/ui.jqgrid.css#L367-L372) of the code of `ui.jqgrid.css`. I suppose that you don't load `ui.jqgrid.css`, load wrong `ui.jqgrid.css` (not from free jqGrid 4.13.6) or you set some CSS rule which overwrite the rule.

Comment: You can easy use Developer Tools (practically the same like on your picture) to see on the right side **which other rule** is wrong. One can see on your picture that you set some rules for `table.ui-jqgrid-btable` wich you **should not do**. You should just use original `ui.jqgrid.css` (or `ui.jqgrid.min.css`)

Comment: Look [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) for simple examples of the usage of free jqGrid.

Comment: oK, that gives me a direction to go.  Thank you for your time sir.

Comment: Ok, that was it.  I was not including the free-jqgrid.css files.  I thought I could just add some css to the site.css file.  Thank you for the solution.  I will try to figure out how to mark your suggestion as the solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify that you inserts the file `ui.jqgrid.min.css` (or `ui.jqgrid.css`) from the same version of jqGrid, which you use.

Some other small suggestions to your code:

- Loading of `grid.locale-en.js` is unneeded in free jqGrid. It's enough to load `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`
- You should use the option `autowidth: true` without specifying the option `shrinkToFit: false` if you need to extend the width of the grid to 100% (to the width of outer container)
- You can remove `colNames` if the values of `name` property of `colModel` are the same strings.
- You should remove `mtype: 'GET',width: '100%',gridview: true,height: 'auto'` options. The values of the options are either default or unneeded.
- I'd recommend you to remove `<div id="gridpager"></div>` and to replace `pager: '#gridpager'` to `pager: true`. jqGrid will automatically create the corresponding div. If you would place some information in the navigator bar by using the methods like `navGrid`, `inlineGrid` and so on, then you will need just  skip `"#gridpager"` parameter and free jqGrid will used the div, which it created  by the usage of `pager: true`.
- I'd recommended you to include Font Awesome 4.x CSS and to use the option `iconSet: "fontAwesome"`. You will improve the look of the icons used by jqGrid. See [the article](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) for more details.
- You should remove `jsonReader` and to return just array of all items from the server (just array, which is the value of `rows` property and skip `{page:1,total:1,records:1, rows: ...}`)